# Yetanotherforum get logged in users details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, yetanotherforum

I can get the logged in username from membership system:

```
// Get user details
var user = Membership.GetUser();
IsLoggedIn = (user != null);
```

But how do I get things like their avatar, user ID and the rest?  Thanks for any help I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% which version you're on, so I'm basing this on the v1.9.5 and greater.

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();

// combined user data takes a membership user and
// will automatically cache repeated requests for user data.
var userData = new CombinedUserData(user);

// get avatar with v1.9.5 and greater
var avatarUrl = this.Get<IAvatar>().GetAvatarUrlForUser(userData);

// get avatar with versions before v1.9.5
var avatarUrl = new YafAvatar().GetAvatarUrlForUser(userData);
```

Comment: It says namespace can't be found, do I need to include anything?

Comment: `var thiss = (yaf_User)user;
        Response.Write(thiss.NumPosts.ToString());` that nearly works but it can't convert `type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' to 'yaf_User'`

Comment: I'm still pretty stuck on this if you can help, I've posted in your forums but the help I get isn't really working :(